# How I maintain aspect ratio for a resized window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a window that contains one QTMovieView.  How do I make it so that resizing of the window will keep the window's aspect ratio the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[window setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(width, height)]
```

More info: [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SizingPlacingWindows.html), [NSWindow class reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)